Consumer transport video stream not working
I am creating a website with streaming capabilities. I am using mediasoup as my webRTC SFU in a react and node environment. I am new but I think I have followed the steps appropriately: Make a worker, get rtp capabilites, create device, create send transport, connect send transport, create recv transport, connect recv transport... I say this because I know messing one of these steps up can possibly be my problem... so here's my problem:
I can't get the consumer video to work..
Here is my connectRecvTransport:
    const connectRecvTransport = async () => {

        await socket.emit('consume', {
            rtpCapabilities: deviceRef.current.rtpCapabilities
        }, async({ params }) => {

            console.log('hit')
            if(params.error){
                console.log('Cannot Consume')
                return
            }

            console.log(params)
            consumer = await consumerTransport.consume({
                id: params.id,
                producerId: params.producerId,
                kind: params.kind,
                rtpParameters: params.rtpParameters
            })

            const {track} = consumer;

            console.log(track)

            remoteVideoRef.current.srcObject = new MediaStream([track])

            socket.emit('consumer-resume')
        })
    }

This fires everything off without error, here is the params object console logged:
{
    "id": "9f565ba7-73b1-4b7f-ae52-3af43a717ab1",
    "producerId": "3620d506-0cf3-4279-9c6c-53b6c4a0126d",
    "kind": "video",
    "rtpParameters": {
        "codecs": [
            {
                "mimeType": "video/VP8",
                "payloadType": 101,
                "clockRate": 90000,
                "parameters": {},
                "rtcpFeedback": [
                    {
                        "type": "transport-cc",
                        "parameter": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "ccm",
                        "parameter": "fir"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "nack",
                        "parameter": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "nack",
                        "parameter": "pli"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "mimeType": "video/rtx",
                "payloadType": 102,
                "clockRate": 90000,
                "parameters": {
                    "apt": 101
                },
                "rtcpFeedback": []
            }
        ],
        "headerExtensions": [
           ***Bunch Of Headers
        ],
        "encodings": [
            {
                "ssrc": 392839613,
                "rtx": {
                    "ssrc": 392839614
                }
            }
        ],
        "rtcp": {
            "cname": "Cu6bT4SfZU86sWTI",
            "reducedSize": true
        },
        "mid": "0"
    }
}

So, my thinking here is OK, everything is working, I'm receiving all the stuff I need, let's turn this into a mediastream and be done with it..
Hence,
remoteVideoRef.current.srcObject = new MediaStream([track])
But, when I created a video tag with a ref like this:
<video ref={remoteVideoRef} autoPlay playsInline style={{ width: '50%' }}></video>
It never plays my video :(
I have tried tweaking it and playing around with the .current, .srcObject, etc to see if it was a syntax error with no success.
I have tried console logging the track, which returns this. (too big to show all but it looks like it should be ok with this stuff...):
MediaStreamTrack {kind: 'video', id: 'cf9c835b-7ef4-42a7-808f-e520afc96664', label: 'cf9c835b-7ef4-42a7-808f-e520afc96664', enabled: true, muted: false, …}

I have even tried tweaking my listenIps as I heard that can be the problem:
    const WebRtcTransport_options ={
      listenIps : [
        {
          ip: '0.0.0.0',
          announcedIp: '127.0.0.1'
        }
      ],
      enableUdp: true,
      enableTcp: true,
      preferUpd: true
    }

So really, The big issue I am having with this problem is I don't know where to look into because both my knowledge of MediaStream syntax and Mediasoup/webRTC is so limited I am not sure I did either correctly.. I hope that the params/track/listenIps will be enough for a seasoned veteran out there to determine if I did my mediasoup config correctly! And that I am hopefully just an idiot and forgot one or two things to do for my video set up.
Thanks!! :)

Everything above is correct in case anyone ever wants to set this up!! I paused it on my server and when I wrote my consumer-resume socket function serverside I didn't put parenthesis so it was never resuming lol...
